# Read local pdf stored in app to pdf viewer in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the nativescript-pdf-viewer (https://github.com/Merott/nativescript-pdf-view) to view pdf in online and locally stored.

I tried a couple answers in github and the documentation https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system but none of theme seems working. I have output for the paths like:

```
const currentAppFolder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp()
const filePath = fileSystemModule.path.join(currentAppFolder.path, "assets", "test.pdf")
this.pdfPath = filePath
```

can get the path but when bind to src of the PdfView element, it returns nothing (no display).

I am using Nativescript-Vue for this project.

Comment: Did you make sure whether the file exists, try `fileSystemModule.File.exists(path)` which will return true if file exists.

Comment: I see it turns false so meaning path cant be found. My aim is I place a pdf, so I place it in the root of project, app/assets/pdf/eq.pdf but it cant be found even the app/assets/pdf is turning false but app/assets is true .. Where is this exactly in the project? I can find it in any nativescript discussions.

Comment: I am using webpack, maybe it didnt copy the files to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was all about my webpack configuration. In this snippet,

//webpack.config.js

```
 // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
 { from: "**/*", context: "assets" },
 ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

And it turns out that what you place in your root path `/app/assets/pdf` (and other files in that assets folder), **WILL REFLECT** in your local platform file, `platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/{the files/folders inside your assets}`

Thus, to call it using file-system of Nativescript,

```
 const currentAppFolder = fs.knownFolders.currentApp()
 const filePath = fs.path.join(currentAppFolder.path, 'pdf', 'eq.pdf')
 //console.log('PDF', fs.File.exists(filePath))
 this.pdfPath = filePath
```

I created a template of a nativescript-vue-typescript called Nitibo. 
Check it out at https://gitlab.com/nativescript-projects/nitibo